# Eclipse plugin or feature that lists all of the collaborators of a certain class?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to port an old game to Android and the code is hard to read. Since I want to port the code systematically with a fine granularity, I want to port the low level classes first. So I was wondering if there is a feature of plugin in Eclipse that allows me to view all of the collaborators of a certain class. For instance, if I had a MazeBuilder class, this class would rely on lower level class such as Nodes and such to build a maze. I would like to port classes such as Node first.

What is difficult is that the code has a ton of these low level classes everywhere and it is a headache to keep track of them all. So is there a plugin that allows me to simply drag/drop a class and then it automatically lists all of the other classes that this particular class associates with?

Answer (score 0):

Type hierarchy view to find descendants. 
Call hierarchy view to find usages of methods and variables. 
Standard JDT has these.